# Python - Tkinter - Padding woes

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have a scrollbar widget that ALWAYS hides the last 15 px under the resize button, is there an option to stop this happening on mac or a padding "under" the widget option?\

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't an option. You need to adjust your padding so that the scrollbar doesn't extend all the way to the bottom of the window. Perhaps the easiest way is to add a statusbar that extends across the bottom of the window.

Comment: thanks to all, i ended up just padding the listbox out of the way of everything - for some striking geometry lol :) (cross platform means that i would rather not fight with what ever borders the computer feels like rendering that day)

Answer (score 0):

Or, you could also try switching to the place() layout manager.

Comment: That won't make any difference. It isn't the choice of geometry manager that is the issue. The issue is, on the Mac there's a resize handle in the bottom-right corner that cannot be covered by a widget.